# capable 64bit but cant install Window 7 64bit? need help tq

Tags: windows-7, installation, motherboard, formatting, window

I have 
Motherboard Asrock 960gc-gs fx
70gb old hard disk,
disk C:20gb 
disk D:50gb
3gb ram
my pc running window 7 32bit
but I already check.that my pc capable 64bit
cant install the 64bit
can anyone tell me requirement for window 7 64bit

Comment: Have you checked what Microsoft say are the prerequisites and confirmed your system fulfills them?  Can you describe the steps you took to install and what errors occured?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to upgrade your windows from a 32-bit version of windows to a 64-bit version of windows.

Unfortunately, you cannot upgrade a 32-bit version of windows to a 64-bit version of windows, due to how significantly different the 64-bit version of windows works from the 32-bit version.

For example, the 64-bit version of windows has 2 "Program Files" folders and 2 "System32" folderse, where the 32-bit version only has one.

In order to install a 64-bit version when a 32-bit version is present, backup everything, then boot directly from the installation medium and perform a clean install. Do note, this will format the C drive, but no other drives are modified.

Answer (score -1):

You missed the most important bit of information - the processor. It's very unlikely, but your processor may be a 32-bit processor.
Also how did you check your system compatibility ? If possible can you tell me what the error you see on screen when you try to install Win7 64 bit ?

[Windows 7 System Requirements](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/10737/windows-7-system-requirements)

Comment: I check my pc system properties. control panel>all control panel item>performance information and tools, 64-bit capable yes. when I install window 7 64bit with my cd. window setup "This installation disc isn't compatible with your version of window. To uograde, you need the correct installation disc. for more information, check your computer system information. To install a new copy of window, restart(boot) your computer using the installation disc, ans then select custom ( advanced))" but aI already boot then suddenly blue screen appear, may hardware or what ever I dont now?

Answer (score -1):

video card maybe?

- 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster <strike>32-bit (x86)</strike> or 64-bit
  (x64) processor*
- 2 GB RAM (64-bit)
- 20 GB (64-bit)
- DirectX 9 graphics device with WDDM 1.0 or higher driver.

If you are trying to "upgrade" within the 32bit OS desktop, restart, boot into CD/USB installer directly during computer start up.

Comment: by the way, re-installing 64bit windows is a full install --- although your data might be still intact, your applications will be need to be re-installed.

Comment: Oh I forgot that my pc running 32bit 86x.. can I Install the window 7 64bit?

Comment: maybe my harddisk need to upgrde 500gb and Upgrade ram until 4gb ram?

Comment: Adrian, I cannot post comment on others' post because I don't have 50 points.  You definitely need to boot from CD -- which you said you did and get blue screen.  Now you must find out why you are getting blue screen.  Burn a copy of memtest software on CD and run it.  This is a low hanging fruit you can test without much effort.  If you have errors on memory it will probably come out really quick within few minutes.